# Inverse, exponentially spaced representation of a count field?

Tags: php, math, exponential, inverse

```
var minCount = 10; // Used as 0, anything below 10 uses will be ignored

User hasMany Attributes

Attribute (id, value, count, worth)
// Count - number of users who associate with this attribute
// Worth - float 0.1 (or a better non-zero number?) to 1
```

An attribute with count of minCount has worth 1.
The attribute(s) with the highest count has the lowest possible worth.
The lesser used attributes are worth more - lower count -> higher worth.

The difference in worth should be exponential:

- Commonly used attributes (high count) - smaller gap between worth
- Uncommon attributes (low count) - larger gap between worth

I'll be using php for now, but psuedo code is equally acceptable - I'd rather just understand how to do it.

Comment: You probably want to use some kind of logarithmic function then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's the problem?

Use the following simple formula:

```
currentWorth = exp(minCount / currentCount - 1)
```

where:
`exp` - exponent of `e`;
`currentCount` - current attribute's count;
`minCount` - least attribute's count.

### Brief explanation:

First consider formula without exponent application:

```
currentWorth = minCount / currentCount
```

For attribute having minimal count (currentCount = minCount):

```
currentWorth = minCount / minCount = 1
```

For attributes having any other count (obviously greater than minCount):

```
(currentWorth = minCount / currentCount) < 1
```

Now let's apply exponential law:

```
currentWorth = exp(minCount / currentCount - 1)
```

For attribute having minimal count (currentCount = minCount):

```
currentWorth = exp(minCount / minCount - 1) = exp(1 - 1) = exp(0) = 1
```

For attributes having any other count (currentCount > minCount):

```
currentWorth = exp(minCount / currentCount - 1)
```

Assuming:

```
t = 1 - minCount / currentCount > 0
```

We'll have:

```
(currentWorth = exp(-t) = 1 / exp(t)) < 1
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly how/why this works? Thanks

Comment: What about a maxCount instead of min?